# Sending Token and Value in browser to Web api

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, token

With Postman I can do a Get and send `Auth-Token` as Header key , and then a value like `Z4TTHmY98=gFw2rG`   and It goes into web api method just fine as it is checked against a custom attributes.

However,  I want to use the browser

**Here is the api that is hit**

```
http://localhost:29001/api/test
```

> My Header Key =  Auth-Token
>   My Header value =  Z4TTHmY98=gFw2rG

After reading some articles, I thought this would work but header is null in stepping through debug of web api method.

Is it possible to do with browser of not?  if so , how?

```
http://localhost:29001/api/test?Auth-Token=Z4TTHmY98=gFw2rG
```

Comment: receiveing the token in controller as string parameter?

Comment: `public ActionResult Test(string AuthToken)` should do with without the dash with the default route setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser opening page doesn't send custom headers. But you can send AJAX request with custom headeres you need. Following example uses [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/test',
  headers: { 'Auth-Token': 'Z4TTHmY98=gFw2rG'}
});
```

**Update**

If you want to send the same headers with each AJAX request by your page you can use `ajaxSetup` + `beforeSend`:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Auth-Token', 'Z4TTHmY98=gFw2rG');
    }
});
```

Comment: That is fine  - hoping browser could do it ,  i'll use postman and then certainly client side as well   thx

Answer (score 0):

Use Webapi 2 Parameter binding.

You can make a call from browser as below

```
 http://localhost:29001/api/test/Z4TTHmY98=gFw2rG/

[HttpGet]
[Route("/test/{AuthToken}")
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromUri] string AuthToken) 
{
    //Do whatever you want to do.
}
```

Careful with the route. It needs to be proper and configured in `webapiconfig`.

Comment: I know how to setup Web Api for this,  I want to know how to send in url in the browser

Comment: Sure -  I could send in URL  ,  problem is that it is sent in headers for a reason ,  I just was hoping for browser to be able to send , but it is not a big deal.   this is certainly a creative way of doing it ,   but i would have to change web api route and method and then the whole entire advanced authorization class that searches the database for key/value pairs is out of the picture as the point is to really have loose coupling / separation of concerns  -  this would force the api controller into a security protocol handshake and that is not how my app works  , web api methods not allowed

Answer (score 0):

AJAX request by page can use like `ajaxSetup` + `beforeSend`:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Auth-Token', 'Z4TTHmY98=gFw2rG');
    }
});
```

**Information**

if you want to call third party API with same then you can use like

```
objHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Key", "value");
objHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "zMXGa8WNQuaBxWazgUhO2dw=");
```